# JasperSoft Server export to network drive

Tags: jasperserver

As seen on the image below, I am trying to schedule PDF export **on a network drive** with JasperSoft Server, but the button is grey ("sortie vers le système de fichiers hôte"). Does anybody know the reason, or how to change it?

[image: JasperSoft Server Export]

I am working locally on my machine with the newest community versions of "JasperSoft Server" and "JasperSoft Studio".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the JasperReports Server Admin Guide, you need to set the enableSaveToHostFS property to true in WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml.

Comment: Hey dada67, thank you for your answer. I do not have this file in my WEB-INF folder. I do have it in: "C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0\buildomatic\conf_source\ieCe". Which I changed as you said but it did not do the trick.

Comment: The WEB-INF folder is in the JRS deployed web application under Tomcat (or other application server where you deployed JRS).

Comment: Indeed! It was in the 
C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF
I don't know why my windows search didn't find it... Thanks for the tip it works perfectly now!